# How to get requested rides details from Uber SDK android and iOS?

Tags: uber-api

Is there any way through which we can get rides details requested using our clientID in android Uber SDK?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-request_id-get

Comment: Thanks! @MarekH, but do you know is there any method available in android Uber SDK through which we can get the ride details?

Comment: No. Uber Rides Android SDK -> Official Android SDK to support:

Ride Request Button
Ride Request Deeplinks
Uber Authentication
REST APIs Tutorial on how to use REST APIs https://github.com/uber/rides-android-sdk